# pyplot not importing, throwing error

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.x

```
  File "/home/darcey/python/opencv/matplotlib.py", line 3, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ImportError: cannot import name pyplot
```

That is the error I get when I run my script:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('color.jpg', 0)
plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'grey', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.xTicks([]), plt.yTicks([])
plt.show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the file that you are running is called `matplotlib.py` as you can see from the first line of the traceback.

```
File "/home/darcey/python/opencv/matplotlib.py", line 3, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ImportError: cannot import name pyplot
```

This name "masks" the installed `matplotlib` module and therefore your code is trying to find `pyplot` within the current file.

The moral of the story - never name your `.py` files the same as any of your installed modules.